# Rails 3 Asset Pipeline and jQuery Mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile, asset-pipeline

If I try and include any `.js` and `.css` files downloaded from the jQuery Mobile website anywhere in the asset pipeline I get all kinds of view render problems, from not finding images to CSS not being applied, to errors in executing the jQuery js file. However, when I use the example code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

in the header of my Rails 3.2.11 app it just works.

Why is this?

I tried inclusion into `application.js` and `application.css` in a number of ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `jquery-rails` and `jquery-mobile` to your Gemfile through their corresponding asset gems.
2. Require their assets from your application.js and application.css or the manifests you've got configured.
3. Do not include the script tag like that in your layout, otherwise you'd be bypassing the Rails Asset Pipeline.

Your Gemfile:

```
group :assets, :development do
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'jquery_mobile_rails'
end
```

Your asset manifests (`application.js` and `application.css` by default) should like like explained at: https://github.com/tscolari/jquery-mobile-rails#installation

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so Mr. Vicente's solution is definitely the simplest, BUT it does not allow you to include custom CSS themes using the JQuery Mobile themeroller. What I have done is basically copy the raw CSS and put that into a 'Custom' css file, which in turn styles the provided themes as I want. Not ideal as you want to build custom themes yourself but OK.

Comment: Don't want to be mean, you should have posted a comment instead of a new answer. Regarding the custom files, you can choose which CSS stylesheets to import by refining the *= require: instead of including all of them, just the ones containing the core code. Have a look at https://github.com/tscolari/jquery-mobile-rails/tree/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets to see your options. You would add your custom theme to e.g. app/assets/stylesheets/theme.sass and require it from your main manifest.